# Is there a specific term in English for the smell of the early morning?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not looking for words like "freshness" for example, but a word that is used exclusively to denote this specific smell.

Comment: What does the morning smell like?

Comment: Some love the smell of napalm in the morning, some wake up and smell the coffee ;)

Comment: ...it smells like victory.

Comment: No, there's no specific word. Did you have an indication there might be such a word (like there's a word for the smell or dusk (no it's not 'dusky')) or were you just curious?

Comment: Loamy. I love me a nice loamy morning.

Comment: Re *loamy*, also see  *[petrichor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrichor)*, “the scent of rain on dry earth”

Comment: Personally, I like the smell of "endless possibilities" in the morning. :-)

Comment: _Loam_, now that's a nice woody sound!

Comment: I think morning smells like coffee, fresh air, and lavendar

Answer (score 1):

The smell of the early morning is usually described as *[dewy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dewy)*.

(An interesting related discussion: [Why does the morning smell so good?](http://blogs.abc.net.au/queensland/2013/02/why-does-the-morning-smell-so-good.html))

Answer (score 0):

While not explicitly limited to morning, the phrase *new-mown hay* is often associated with early morning smells, as in this [folk song](http://www.traditionalmusic.co.uk/folk-song-lyrics/New_Mown_Hay.htm)

> As I strolled out one bright new morn,
>
> All under the new mown hay, O,
>
> I there did espy a fair pretty maid,
>
> Under the new-mown hay, O, under the new-mown hay.